# Why passing jest this component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

Input component must have props "name".
But Jest is passing test.
It doesn't make sense.
How to fix it?

```
class Input extends React.Component<
  {
    errorMassage: string;
    label: string;
    name: string;
    value: number | string;
    type: "text" | "number" | "price";
    onFocus: () => void;
    onChange: (name?: string, e?: MouseEvent) => void;
    autoFocus: boolean;
  },
  {}
......
```

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Input from "../Input";

describe("<Input>", () => {
  it("renders without crashing", () => {
    const div = document.createElement("div");
    ReactDOM.render(<Input />, div);
  });
});
```

Comment: thats more of a typescript question

Comment: Is the test file javascript? Typescript check types on compilation, not runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to put the props as `type InputProps = {...}` and then set the React Component as that type like `React.Component<InputProps>`

Additionally I think it passes, since that jest test literally just tests if it renders to the page. Not whether it renders correctly. Additionally, do you have any default props that is may be basing itself off from?